# Why doesn't "opengl software" work on Mac OS X Matlab?

Tags: macos, matlab, opengl

So I've found a solution to using transparencies in Matlab and that is the command

```
>> opengl software
Warning: Switching to software OpenGL rendering is not supported on the MAC platform 
> In opengl at 76
```

This feature isn't allowed in Matlab on Mac OS X. Can someone tell me why and if there is a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/opengl.html): "Note that Macintosh systems do not support software OpenGL." Matlab does have OpenGL *hardware* rendering, though, and AFAIK any Mac you're likely to use supports hardware OpenGL. Try `opengl hardware`; if that works, it should do transparencies also.

Comment: That's strange; Apple reckon they do have a software renderer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pg_concepts/opengl_pg_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH208-SW1

Comment: I guess a software renderer exists, but matlab apparently doesn't use it.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work either. I get the same error. The axes are still missing.

Comment: @Griff it's true that this answer doesn't help with using software OpenGL on OSX versions of matlab; but there's unlikely to be a solution outside of getting MathWorks to support it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this error as well when using hardware OpenGL rendering on a mac and have been unable to fix it directly. Let me guess: you are trying to display a plot with transparencies, so MATLAB forces OpenGL hardware rendering, but has missing axes and/or titles, labels, etc. You can work around this problem by exporting the figure as a vector graphic. I use plot2svg and then open it up in Illustrator and the plots is exactly as it should be, with correct axes and labels. Hope that helps.